# OpenMP on Mac not working anymore

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc, clang, openmp

I had OpenMP compiling and executing in C/C++ on my Mac but then I formatted and reinstalled a fresh copy of OS X. I believe the only difference in the setup was that I had Xcode 5 before the format, and now I have Xcode 6.

Now I get `fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found`

I read this has something to do with clang and gcc, but, my confusion lies with why did it work before and now its not working?

Comment: might you be missing the "omp.h" file?

Answer (score 1):

After some research I seem to have found an answer.

GCC included in the latest version of Xcode (Xcode 6) is only a symbolic link to clang. Since clang does not support OpenMP at this time, you need to install a different version of GCC. The easiest way to do this would be to use Homebrew or MacPorts.

Keep in mind that even when you do this you will probably need to alter your `$PATH` to have `/usr/local` come before `/usr/bin`. This is because Homebrew will have placed your newly installed GCC in `/usr/local`. Also, some implementations may name the command `gcc-49` instead of plain `gcc`.

Comment: If you do it with MacPorts, you don't have to alter your `PATH` ordering, all you have to do is to select `gcc49` with `sudo port select --set gcc mp-gcc49`

Comment: Another option is to try the openmp clang implementation here https://clang-omp.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

Mac OSX uses clang.The gcc compiler in OS X does not support OpenMP. To use this feature a new gcc compiler needs to be installed.

Go to Terminal, if you have not installed Hombrew, install it:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://`enter code here`raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

then install new version of gcc

```
brew reinstall gcc --without-multilib
```

This will not make changes to the existing gcc compiler installed by Xcode as we are reinstalling it.

After running the command given below compile the files using the new  version of gcc using the syntax : gcc-version -fopenmp filename.c

To find the version type gcc and then press tab. This will list out all the possible variants of gcc. The version number can be found out from this. For example : gcc-6, gcc-4.9,etc